# Behavior of weighted sum when weights are functions

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $w_n$ be a (deterministic) sequence of bounded real-valued functions on the interval $[a,b]$, and let $X_n$ be a sequence of IID random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$.  Define the random function
$$
  Y_n(t) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i(t) X_i.
$$
It is very easy to show that $Y_n(t_0) = O_p(n^{-1/2})$ for any fixed value $t_0 \in [a,b]$.  What conditions on $w_n$ imply that $\sup_{t \in [a,b]} |Y_n(t)| = O_p(n^{-1/2})$?